# How to get new txt files as index from list?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing

```
#working code for one file
directory = r'C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\output'
list1 = os.listdir(directory)
length = len(list1)
print(list1)
print(list1[0])

with open(r"C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\output\1.xml") as infile, open(r'C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\out\output.xml', 'w') as outfile:
    for line in infile:
        if not line.strip(): continue  # skip the empty line
        outfile.write(line)
```

dir:

> ['0.xml', '1.xml', '2.xml', '3.xml']

Desired output:

4 xml files w/o whitespaces.

How to do this for every file in the list1 list? I'm so stuck. Please help

Comment: do what? explain your question better, see [ask] a question

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over input files, output files, or both? Or something else?

Comment: Thank you Moosefeather. I'm trying to iterate over both

Comment: Check it now @MaxFH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to update the files in place (for which I would first recommend that you make backups in case you have some sort of failure in the middle of an update and end up with a file in an inconsistent state), then the following would, for example, remove empty lines from all files with filetype `xml` (you can change the pattern match to be whatever you want):

```
from pathlib import Path


for path in Path(r'C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\output').glob('*.xml'):
    with open(path, 'r+') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        f.seek(0, 0)
        for line in lines:
            if line.strip() != '':
                f.write(line)
        f.truncate()
```

**If you want new, numbered output files, then:**

```
from pathlib import Path




n = 0
for path in Path(r'C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\output').glob('*.xml'):
    with open(path, 'r') as infile, open(fr'C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\output\output{n}.xml'), 'w') as outfile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.strip() != '':
                outfile.write(line)
    n += 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Booboo! Your first code worked. With the second code, I get an ValueError: I/O operation on closed file. However you have helped so much. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry about that. It should have been `as outfile:` on second code version. I have corrected the code.

Comment: Thanks, it doesn't generate any errors, however I get one output file. However, no worries as the first code is more than sufficient. Thank you!

Comment: I needed a second cup of coffee to awaken my brain. I made a second correction. But again, when updating in place, if you lose power in the middle of an update, the file contents may be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

here's the solution.

```
directory = r'C:\Users\Max12\Desktop\xml\pdfminer\UiPath\output'
list1 = os.listdir(directory)
length = len(list1)
for i in range(length):
    data = open(directory+'//'+list1[i],'rb').read()
    out = open(f'{directory}\out\{list1[i]}','wb').write(data)
```

Comment: no, as seperate txt files if possible Shekhar!